# how to pass contact name, phone, accountid using url

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a requirement in cti like 
when i am dialing existed contact number

1. then it will open that contact using window.open(url) in javascript
   method else.
2. open contact creation page and prepopulate phone, contact name(these phone and contact name coming from directory) using    window.open(url) in javascript method.
   i dont know exactly how to form url using these parameters. Please help me

   ```
   function showContactForm(contact_number, contactName, callLogId)
   ```

   {

   ```
   if(contactName && contactName !="UnKnown"){
       var tx=contactName.split(" ");
       var firstname;
       var lastname;
       if(tx.length==2){
           firstname = tx[0];
           lastname = tx[1];
   }
   }

   if(contact_number != 'UnKnown'){
           window.open('/003/e?name_firstcon2='+firstname+'&name_lastcon2='+lastname+'&con10='+contact_number, '_parent'); 
       } else {
           window.open('/003/e', '_parent'); 
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method is to use the console of the browser to inspect form elements.

You have to copy the "id" attibute of the input tag and use it in your URL hack.

For example, I inspected this element in the HTML ofthe "new contact page" :

```
<input id="name_firstcon2" maxlength="40" name="name_firstcon2" size="20" tabindex="4" type="text">
```

This HTML element is used for the firstname input fields.

for your url hack, you have to add in the GET parameters **"name_firstcon2"** like this /003?name_firstcon2=YOUR_NAME

Comment: Hi @akram thanks a lot, its worked fine in classic. But its not showing predefined values in lightning. I used above code please see that once. Please any suggestions...